# Many installed apps crash after OTA update to Android 4.2

Tags: crashes, ota-update

I had run over the air update from Android 4.1 to 4.2 on my Samsung Grand GT-I9082. It seems to have completed fine (screen with robot and progress bar for a while, then some messages about "optimizing" and "running" applications, then boot).

After update the phone itself works fine, however a lot of third party apps now crash on launch with "Application [name] has been stopped" (loose translation since my phone interface is not in English). It is consistent and specific to the app - either it always crashes or it just works normally. The one slight exception is Chrome which opens and closes immediately, but doesn't give the message.

1. Clearing cache for the app doesn't fix it
2. Uninstalling app completely and re-installing does fix it (so far - for those few I did it for)

What else can I try?

At this point I guess reinstalling every crashing app would fix them, but that seems very boring and menial option, not to mention losing settings and data in those apps where it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your device is rooted, and you have a custom recovery installed: Wipe the [dalvik](/questions/tagged/dalvik) cache. Next boot will take a little longer (as the Dalvik cache has to be rebuilt), but the problem should be gone.

If the above is not an option, you could try to backup the affecgted apps and their data using e.g. [Helium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/helium-app-sync-and-backup/com.koushikdutta.backup), then uninstall the apps, and restore them (including their data) from their backup. This way their Dalvik cache would be rebuilt as well, you don't lose your data, and *Helium* can do that in a batch-process to save you a bunch of clicks.

Comment: Phone not rooted. Do you consider this is issue to be with "dalvik" cache for certain or it is just a one possible reason? From look at tag it seems I can't do anything with it without root, so could as well start on reinstalls. :\

Comment: I consider it a very likely reason, as a OS version change took place (which might introduce a newer Dalvik version as well). Dalvik cache for an app is created on install or when missing, ADB/Helium backup will not store this so it would be re-created then. Just try it for yourself with one app first and see, what do you have to lose? :)

Comment: Reinstalled everything crashing. Helium seems to be mostly waste of time since it failed to restore data for all but one games I have and those few are kind of only unrecoverable data on my phone. I am glad I don't care much for highscores.. :)

Comment: That's most likely not the fault of Helium, but rather a bug in your Android version (I had the same on several devices, and it also did not work with plain `adb restore` which Helium is the frontend for, while it worked smoothly on others).

Answer (score -1):

Doing a factory reset of your device may solve the problem. Make sure that you do not restore from a back-up and set up your device as fresh. This would be a permanent fix for your problem. Otherwise, 3rd-party apps will crash every time you update them. Uninstalling & reinstalling is only a temporary fix.

**Back up important files to Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.

Comment: The problem user is facing is due to permissions gone awry. Factory reset will erase all the data in the phone which is not preferred by the user.

Comment: _3rd-party apps will crash every time you update them_ - this was not what happened in my case, it was one time corruption (or something) at time of update and going forward all apps install/update perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

In Developer Options, Try changing the Runtime. If **ART** is set, it could cause a problem because currently 95% of Android apps run on DVM (Dalvik Virtual Memory).

Comment: OP says they're using 4.2; ART didn't become available until 4.4 AFAIK.